# Custom Vimeo API embed not autoplaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, vimeo

I have a quite specific issue regarding Chrome's new feature where they stop autoplaying videos.

On our site we wanted the page to load as quickly as possible, so only insert a new Vimeo embed object when a user has chosen to click to watch a video. Eg. the showreel on our homepage:

https://www.splinter.co.uk/

The problem arises because we use our own custom play button, so Chrome doesn't recognise that as a user-interaction, so it doesn't think that the user has chosen to view the video, therefore it blocks the autoplay option (which works fine in Safari).

I wondered if anyone else has had this problem, and if anyone can think of a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the VOD home page of Vimeo you can find a technique that is used for a case like this. https://vimeo.com/ondemand

You can preload the Vimeo player when the user hovers over your custom play button so that at the time they click the [Vimeo player.js API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) can be used to initiate playback. `player.play()`

If that is not sufficient it might be needed to load the player on page load and just keep it hidden, on the button press reveal the player and use the API to initiate playback.